# Error with "Self" [Self presentmodalviewcontroller]

Tags: xcode, parsing, authentication

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
   }

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc]init];
    login.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton;
    [self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];
  
     
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

I get an error saying "Self" is depreciated in iOS 6. Any Ideas on how to fix this? This is for the login screen on Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.